# HTML code to check IP

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, ip

I need the html or java code that checks your IP. Let me put it in simple terms.

Check IP. If IP = X then run blah blah blah.

If its not possible to do this in html but it is possible. Tell me the basics because I only know so much.

Comment: you first show us what you have attempted, this is not a 'we write code for you' site.

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not have a way to get a user's IP, it is a markup language not a programming language.

We can't do this with JavaScript either, at least not pure JS.

PHP, however, is able to do that. In your HTML you would put

```
<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

Note however, this value can be spoofed. See [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php) for all the juicy details.